# Javascript say if a folder is child of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, tree, directory

I have these strings which are addresses of files and folder:

1. ../../../folder1/sub1/sub12/
2. ../../../folder1/
3. ../../../another-folder/

I want to compare them using javascript - possibily jquery - to see if for example string 1 have a part egual to string 2 but something more saying that string 1 is child of string 2.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your string can contain also absolute paths or paths containing `..` not only at the beginning I would recommend checking if `.indexOf` return `0` instead of anything that is not `-1`.

It can help with cases like.

```
var path1 = "/rootFolder/";
var path2 = "../folder/rootFolder/";

if (path2.indexOf(path1) === 0) {
  console.log("You want this");  // won't get executed => good
}

if (path2.indexOf(path1) !=-1) {
  console.log("You don't want this"); // will get executed => bad
}
```

Comment: please can you make an example of indexof returning 0?

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi For example `console.log("../folder/1".indexOf("../folder"));`. When the string is at the exact beginning of the other string then the starting index is 0 so `indexOf` will retun `0`.

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like the following

```
var path1 = "../../../folder1/";
var path2 = "../../../folder1/sub1/sub12/";

if (path2.indexOf(path1) != -1){
 //path2 is a sub of path 1
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` can return `0` which is falsy

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi when `path2` is starting with `path1` - then the starting index is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indexOf` method to find whether one string is a part of another string.

From [w3schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp):

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a
>   specified value in a string.
>
> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

```
var test = "../folder/subfolder1";
var test2 = "../folder";
if (test.indexOf(test2) !=-1) {
     alert(test + " is a subfolder of " + test2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string1.indexOf(string2) != -1){
//string2 is present in string1
}
else{
//string2 is not present in string1
}
```